# mySQL structure/relation ideas

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have two tables: 
1. `Person`
2. `Record`

Multiple rows from table `person` can be connected to one row from `record`.
But if i have one person that is connected to multiple records, what is the best way to connect this?

Record no.1 = Person no.1 , **Person no.2**, Person no.3
Record no.2 = Person no.4, Person no.5, **Person no.2**

Is it the best way to create a new table called `relations` and add two columns: `recordid`, `personid` . So it would look like this:

```
recordid  |  personid
    1            1
    1            2
    1            3
    2            4
    2            5
    2            2
```

I am doing this becaues if a user changes data for one person, it should be displayed also in other records that have same person atached to it.

Basicly i would get what rows from `person` are conncted to rows from `record`  by doing this:

```
SELECT `record`.`data` FROM `record` LEFT JOIN `relation` ON `record`.`id`=`relation`.`recordid` LEFT JOIN `person` ON `relation`.`personid`=`person`.`id`
```

I would use this kind of joining for getting the data and for all the searches through records (by name, surname, and a lot of other parametes), and i could have more than 100k rows in a person teble and more than 100k rows in person table.

Is there some other simplier and faster way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the right usage.

However, depending on what you want, an Inner Join may be more faster than a Left Outer Join, particularly since you speak of more than 100k records etc. Of course, it would fetch only records those where an entry is present and matched.

Also, depending on what you do after running the query, you can write separate queries to find records that match and do not match and display accordingly.